# Lifecycle of a subactivity

Tags: android, android-activity, subactivity, activity-lifecycle

If an Activity starts another by startActivityForResult(), what happens to that subactivity if the parent is finished?

Comment: I want to know how u are going to kill the parent activity after leaving the parent activity?

Comment: Yes, perhaps that's the point. I don't know if that could be done in a manual way. Anyway, there have to be guarantees that the runtime won't kill it..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If Activity A calls `startActivityForResult()` (starting up Activity B), and A is finished, nothing happens to B, AFAIK.

Comment: Ok. that would mean if resources are low, the system may not be able to deliver the results in the callback. But as that would certainly only happen in extreme situations, I can live with that answer. Thanks.

Comment: @cody: In low-memory situations, Activity A is not finished. When the user BACK-buttons out of Activity B, Activity A would be restored from its instance state. An activity is `finish()`'d only if you call `finish()` on it, or the user does it via the BACK button.